# Estimating the measure of a sum of subsets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A,B \subset \mathbb R^n$ be compact measurable subsets and let $A + B = \{ a+b \mid a \in A, b \in B \}$. If $m$ is the Lebesgue measure, is it possible to relate $m(A + B)$ to $m(A)$ and $m(B)$?

In $\mathbb R$, for instance, $m([a,b] + [c,d]) = m([a+c, b+d]) = (b-a) + (d-c) = m([a,b]) + m([c,d])$. I would be happy, in general, with something like $m(A+B) \le m(A) + m(B)$ but I do not know whether this is possible.

Comment: Try links from search for _volume of minkowski sum_ : https://www.google.com/search?q=volume+of+minkowski+sum&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1 That's mostly about convex sets, but may help.

Comment: @EthanBolker: I've searched for "measure" instead of "volume" and have got uninteresting results. Anyway, [it seems that $m(A+B) \le m(A) + m(B)$ is just a nice dream.](http://geometrie.kma.zcu.cz/index.php/www/content/download/582/1635/file/Vorau_2007.pdf)

Comment: I think the above inequality is obvious

Comment: The sets have to be fat for there to be any chance of saying anything.  In 2 dimensions, you can take both to be segments $A = \{t a:  0 \le t \le 1\}$ and $B = \{s b: 0 \le s \le 1\}$, both of measure zero,  and then $A + B$ will be a paralleogram of positive measure.  Since the sets have to be fat, you might as well assume they are convex, at least for the first go,  and then it seems there is a literature on the subject, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_volume

Comment: You may be interested in Brunn -Minkowsky Inequality: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/brunn-minkowski-inequality/

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  in the link looks like for 1 dimension we need some $ C $ such that $A+B \subset C $ and $\mu (C) \ge \mu (A) + \mu (B) $

Comment: One should not even hope that $\mu (A+B) \leq \mu (A) +\mu (B)$. If C is the cantor set then $C+C=[0,2]$.